# Como rotacionar imageView 90º?

Tags: java, android, mobile, imagem

Ola, estou fazendo um app de edição de Imagem e preciso saber como fazer a rotação de 90º de uma imageView e substituir a original pela imagem que rotou 
Pesquisei nos sites e achei esta forma de fazer, porém quando realizo a rotação, a imagem fica muito pequena e não consigo rotar ela novamente. Agradeço desde já, toda dica e ajuda é bem vinda!

```
public void rotacionar(View v){
    resultView;  //é a minha imageView
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    resultView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    m.postRotate(180, 200, 200);
    resultView.setImageMatrix(m);
}
```

Comment: Não precisa fazer na mão, existem várias bibliotecas que já fazem isso por padrão.

Comment: Saberia me indicar alguma? Ficaria muito grato

achei outras formas de fazer com animation, RotateAnimation, setAnimation, etc.. Mas não consigo substituir o resultado rotado em 180º pelo inicial..

Comment: A vantagem de fazer a mão é poupar processamento. Se a ImageView será sempre visualizada rotacionada é melhor fazê-lo a mão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o Seguinte!

Primeiro vamos transformar um `Drawable` em `Bitmap`:

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            }
        }

        if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Vamos rotacionar a imagem, não o `ImageView`:

```
 Bitmap myImg = drawableToBitmap(imageView.getDrawable() );

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Após rotacionar, adicionamos ela no `ImageView`:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(rotated);
```

Espero ter Ajudado!

Saudações!

Comment: achei bem interessante esta forma, mas ali na primeira linha onde colocas (R.drawable.minha_imagem) que esta a questão. A imagem que quero já esta dentro da imageView, portanto, preciso saber como pegar a imagem da imageView, modificar ela e devolver.

Caso possa auxiliar nisso fico muito grato e obrigado pela dica :)

Comment: Editei minha resposta! veja se lhe serve! Saudações!

Comment: agora foi, obrigado pela ajuda!! :D